# An interesting math puzzle

Tags: math, puzzle

Although it is not very programming related but I think SO could be of some assistance:

```
A zeroless pandigital number of base 10 is a number with all the 
distinct digits 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. 
For example, the first zeroless pandigital number of base 10 is 123456789.
Find a zeroless pandigital number of base 10 such that the numbers up to the nth 
digit is divisible by n i.e. the number formed by 1st, 2nd and 3rd digit 
is divisible by 3, the number formed by 1 to 6 digits is divisible by 6 
and so on.
```

I started with thinking as assuming the no. to be "abcdefghi" and stating that a can be 
any number between "1-9" b can be only the even ones, e is surely 5 and so on.

But I am not able to find how to go from here.

Any help/or better method will be appreciated

Comment: When you say "all the distinct digits".. does that mean the digits should appear exactly once, or can a digit be repeated, as long as all digits are present atleast once?

Comment: Please specify which Project Euler problem this is.

Comment: b,d,f,h -- all must be even. e must be 5.

Comment: The point of the Euler Project is that you should solve the problems yourself, not have others solve them for you...

Comment: Simple depth-first search tells me in less than one second plus 5 minutes coding: 381654729

Comment: Not a Project Euler problem. All problems on one page: http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=view_all

Comment: Who would use a computer to solve this?  It's easily solvable by hand.

Answer (score 5):

Why are all the answers in the comments? I hope I'm not breaking some sort of etiquette I don't know about by posting an answer.

`(b, d, f, h)` have to be the even numbers `(2, 4, 6, 8)` in some order, `e` must be `5`, so `(a, c, g, i)` have to be the numbers `(1, 3, 7, 9)` in some order. Once you've made these observations, there are only `4!*4!=576` possibilities, so check them all.

Comment: Am I the only person who shouts the number when they see a factorial? I hope not.

Comment: You're not alone. Depending on the company I'm in, I sometimes say "FOUR times FOUR equals five seventy six."

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to reduce the number of possibilities, or at least reduce the calculations expended.

b must be even.

(a + b + c) must be divisible by 3.

d must be even, but also (2c+d) must be divisible by 4.

e must be 5 or zero, and since 0 is not an option in a pandigital number that does not include 0, then e must be 5.

f must be even. But also, (a + b + c + d + e + f) must be divisible by 3. Since we already know that (a + b + c) is divisible by 3, then this tells us that (d + e + f) must be divisible by 3.

(a -2b -3c - d + 2e + 3f + g) must be divisible by 7.

h must be even, but also for divisibility by 8, we need only check that (4f+2g+h) is so divisible.

Since b, d, f, and h must all be even digits, then a,c,e,g,i must be only odd digits.

Finally, ALL 9 digit pandigital numbers that do not include 0 are divisible by 9. So no tests need be done for that at all!

Answer (score 1):

The two-digit number **cd** (odd-even) should be divisible by 4 and the three digit number **fgh**(even-odd-even) should be divisible by 8.

Thus, considering the possibilities, **d** have to be 2 or 6, and **h** have to be 4, 2 or 6

This may help to reduce the number of possibilities.